# jQuery datepicker; min/max date and animation

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I've assembled the code below and it works for the most part.  What is NOT working are the first 2 lines of the function, concerning min/max date and the animation.  Everything else is perfect.  Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
/*  jQuery ready function. Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.  */
    $(document).ready(
      /* This is the function that will get executed after the DOM is fully loaded */
      function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker('option', {minDate: 0, maxDate: "+1Y"});
        $("#datepicker").datepicker('option', {showAnim: 'drop'});
        $("#datepicker").datepicker('option', {changeMonth: false})
        $("#datepicker").datepicker('option', {changeYear: false})
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "DD, MM d, yy" }).val()
        $("#datepicker").datepicker('option', {altField: "#altDate"})
        $("#datepicker").datepicker('option', {altFormat: "yy-mm-dd"})

      }

    );
</script>
```

SOLVED:  By moving the two top lines to the bottom, this fixes the issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
/*  jQuery ready function. Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.  */
    $(document).ready(
      /* This is the function that will get executed after the DOM is fully loaded */
      function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker('option', {changeMonth: false})
        $("#datepicker").datepicker('option', {changeYear: false})
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "DD, MM d, yy" }).val()
        $("#datepicker").datepicker('option', {altField: "#altDate"})
        $("#datepicker").datepicker('option', {altFormat: "yy-mm-dd"})
        $("#datepicker").datepicker('option', {minDate: 0, maxDate: "+1Y"});
        $("#datepicker").datepicker('option', {showAnim: 'drop'});
      }

    );
</script>
```

Comment: SOLVED:            I moved the top two lines to the bottom of the function and that solved it.

Comment: note that you can declare all your settings together by using datepicker({option1: value1, option2: value2}), see here: http://jsfiddle.net/a0jwgn3m/

Comment: Thank you, Danilo... much better!